# Different WAN speeds from different computers on same 1Gbit LAN

Tags: networking, router, lan, wan

I have 3 computers on same LAN connected to WAN over a switch.

Two of them have 40Mbit/s/3Mbit/s download/upload speed and 3rd has 3mbit/3mbit download and upload speed according to (speedtest.net)

I checked LAN communications between two PCs including this one using `iperf` and LAN is indeed about 1Gbit/s.

Why external speed is so different - they all connected to same switch and have near-perfect LAN performance.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: There is literally no information here to find a solution to this problem... Have you tried alternative speed testing sites like fast.com or testmy.net? This could also be related to hardware differences, software installed and running, ufw, services, resources, etc. Without more information there is no way this question could possibly be answered.

Comment: What kind of information to show? and fast.com gives same results

Comment: Are you using a router? Or is the WAN line plugged directly into a switch? Are the PCs assigned public or private IP addresses (if you have a router)? Do you pay for multiple IP addresses?

Comment: All behind NAT. Behind same switch. The switch is connected to router. The speed of one laptop for WAN much slower, in LAN/switch 1GB. Changed switch ports, cables the result the same. After reboot speed goes back to normal than at some point drops to slow one.

Comment: Are you using a VPN or some sort of special antivirus which may scan incoming traffic on the affected PC?

Comment: @SamForbis no, also note it is Linux...

Also via WIFI to same router I get 40Mbits/s as expected. Only over LAN I get slow connection to WAN - local LAN is fast in between local machines

Comment: See if this helps you out. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366220/ubuntu-16-04-minimal-extremely-slow-internet-connection